# Prevent Hotspot from automatically starting after system startup

Tags: networking, 18.04, hot-spot

I used Hotspot to share my Internet connection with my phone for some time. Since then, whenever I start my PC, Hotspot directly starts and I can not use Wi-Fi (on my PC) unless I turn the Hotspot connection off.
Is there a way to stop Hotspot from automatically start?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I fixed my problem by following these steps:

1. Run the command `nmcli con show`.

   - A list of the known networks will be displayed.
2. Run the command `nmcli con mod <connection-name> connection.autoconnect no`.

   - This will prevent the Hotspot connection from starting automatically.

**(Optional)** If you want to delete the Hotspot connection permanently, follow these steps:

- Run `ls /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections`.
- A list of the known networks will be displayed.
- Run `sudo rm <connection-name>`.